# How to decrypt AWS Lambda Environment Variables

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using the example code provided on the Lambda console when I 'encrypt' the environment variables.

I've created a key, and given the Role "kms:Decrypt" permission.

My function times out when trying to "decrypt" the variable, but runs fine when not encrypted. The logs do not provide any errors.

Here is the code used to decrypt:

```
private String decryptKey(String keyName) {
    byte[] encryptedKey = Base64.decode(keyName);
    AWSKMS client = AWSKMSClientBuilder.defaultClient();
    DecryptRequest request = new DecryptRequest()
     .withCiphertextBlob(ByteBuffer.wrap(encryptedKey));
    ByteBuffer plainTextKey = client.decrypt(request).getPlaintext();
    return new String(plainTextKey.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

And it's called like this...

```
return decryptKey(System.getenv(variableName));
```

I took this code as is, assuming that, as it runs from within Lambda, the 'defaultClient' knows the region, account, etc.

Edit:

These are the log lines:

> START RequestId: 92419f62-fa84-11e6-876d-99aa85e9b481 Version: $LATEST
>   END RequestId: 92419f62-fa84-11e6-876d-99aa85e9b481
>   REPORT RequestId: 92419f62-fa84-11e6-876d-99aa85e9b481    Duration: 15001.41 ms > Billed Duration: 15000 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 64 MB
>   2017-02-24T11:30:13.908Z 92419f62-fa84-11e6-876d-99aa85e9b481 Task timed out 
>   after 15.00 seconds

If I run without EncryptionHelpers, but still try and unencrypt the variables I get this, which is as expected:

> {
>    "errorMessage": "Input is expected to be encoded in multiple of 4 bytes but found: 13",
>    "errorType": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException",
>    "stackTrace": [
>      "com.amazonaws.util.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:198)",
>      "com.amazonaws.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:89)",
>      "scripts.Environment.decryptKey(Environment.java:56)",
>      "scripts.Environment.getEnvVariable(Environment.java:38)",
>      "scripts.Environment.(Environment.java:30)",
>      "scripts.CreateNewDatabase.createNewConfigDatabase(CreateNewDatabase.java:33)",
>      "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)",
>      "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)",
>      "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)",
>      "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)"
>    ]
>   }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kms.decrypt() are api calls which need internet and your issue seems to be a problem of connection to internet of your lambda.

To be sure, you should look into the logs. In this case, you'll find something like

> Starting new HTTPS connection (1): kms.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

To resolve this issue, you should associate the lambda to a subnet that has access to internet -
 a private subnet with a NAT gateway.

You'll find more information in the part "Internet Access for Lambda Functions" of this [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html)

Comment: Thank you. The logs (see edit) don't mention anything about the problem. If there is a way to log this stuff that would be helpful. In the end I created a private subnet, put the Lambda in there, and routed 0.0.0.0/0 traffic to a NAT in another 'public' subnet. (+ appropriate Security Groups)